# Transform $\dot{x}=f(t)g(x,t)$ to $\dot{y} =g(y, t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, numerical-calculus

I try to solve IVP for ode
$$
\dot{x} = f(t)g(x,t).
$$

The $f(t)$ is relative simple and it is easy to get information about $\int fdt$ and $\frac{df}{dt}$.

I want to find a transformation $y=y(x)$ or $y=y(x, t)$ such that
$$
\dot{y} = g(y, t).
$$

My question is does such $y$ exist? If exists, what is the formula?

Comment: We can start with the simplest cases to gain more intuition. But I find it is hard even to find $y$ when $f(t)$ is very simple like $f(t)=t^2$.

Comment: If $$\left\{\begin{array}{rl}{\bf u}'(t)&=&\beta(t)  g({\bf u}(t))\\ {\bf u}(0)&=&{\bf u}_0\end{array}\right.,$$ to some $\beta(t)\neq 0$ (in a way that the ${\bf u}(t)$ exists).  It follows that, if you let $s=\rho(t)$, with $\rho(0)=0$ and $\rho'(t)=\beta(t)$, then $$\left\{\begin{array}{rlrr}{\bf u}'(s)&=&\displaystyle\frac{d\,{\bf u}}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}&=& g({\bf u}(s))\\ {\bf u}(0)&=&{\bf u}_0\end{array}\right..$$

Comment: @JoséCFerreira, Thanks. I missed the basic chain rule. Yes, you solve the problem.